# Kubernetes/Openshift volumeAttributes in volume manifest

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, persistent-volumes

I would like to set a samba server in Openshift, using this instruction https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb/tree/master/deploy/example/smb-provisioner

but I have a question - what should be here in PersistenVolume manifest in volumeAttributes/source? :
I assume {app name}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local/{share_name}

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-smb
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0777
    - file_mode=0777
    - vers=3.0
  csi:
    driver: smb.csi.k8s.io
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: unique-volumeid  # make sure it's a unique id in the cluster
    volumeAttributes:
      source: "//smb-server.default.svc.cluster.local/share"
    nodeStageSecretRef:
      name: smbcreds
      namespace: default
```

https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb/blob/master/deploy/example/smb-provisioner/pv-smb-csi.yaml

service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: smb-server
  labels:
    app: smb-server
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: smb-server
  ports:
    - port: 445
      name: smb-server
```

With this configuration I receive an error in deployment:

MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pv-smb"
Output: mount error: could not resolve address for smb-server.default.svc.cluster.local: Unknown error

Could you please advice?

Comment: Is there a service named `smb-server` in your `default` namespace? If not, you'll need to update that path to match you actual deployment (`<service_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`).

Comment: yes, I have service smb-server:                                                                           
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: smb-server
  labels:
    app: smb-server
spec:
  type: ClusterIP 
  selector:
    app: smb-server
  ports:
    - port: 445
      name: smb-server

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. This csi driver can not access kubernetes internal network. Service as LoadBalancer did what needed.